# Bulk update in SQLAlchemy on a JSONB column

Tags: python, postgresql, orm, sqlalchemy, jsonb

What is the correct way of updating multiple rows - specifically the JSONB field inside the row without setting the whole column (but adding new keys to the JSONB column)?

Something like -

```
data_mappings = [{
    'id': 1, 
    'dynamic': {'new_key': 'some_value'}
}, ...]

session.bulk_update_mappings(Data, data_mappings)
session.commit()
```

The '*dynamic*' column should remain with the old data and will have the *new_key* in it.

Comment: are you able to figure out the way to do the JSONB update with bulk_update_mappings?

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution. PostgreSQL actually supports update multi json fields in single query.

```sql
UPDATE a_table 
SET json_column= json_column :: jsonb || '{"key": {"key1": 11}, "key2": {"key2": 22}}' 
WHERE
    id = 'the_id';
```

The SQLAlchemy does:

```py
stmt =  update(Atable).values(
        json_column=(Atable.json_column.cast(JSONB) + json.dumps({"key": {"key1": 11}, "key2": {"key2": 22}}))).where(Atable.id == "the_id")
print(stmt) # check the raw sql
db.session.execute(stmt)
db.session.commit()
```

update multi records with SQLAlchemy:

```py
data_mappings = [{
    'id': 1, 
    'dynamic': json.dumps({'new_key': 'some_value'})
},]
stmt =  update(Atable).values(
        json_column=(Atable.json_column.cast(JSONB) + bindparam['dynamic'])).where(Atable.id == bindparam('id'))
print(stmt) 
db.session.execute(stmt, data_mapping)
db.session.commit()
```

update one field refer to SQLAlchemy func.jsonb_set